# laravel 8, the accessor and the mutator not working

Tags: laravel-8, accessor, mutators

I have a table `leads`, and a model `Lead`, inside the model I have a getter and setter for a certain attribute, however, it's not working.
using `dd(1);` inside shows that the function is never called.

why?

Model:

```
class Lead extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    //  The name of the field in the database is `lead_image_alt`.

    public function getLeadImageAltAttribute($value)
    {
        // dd(1); // never executed
        return "Some text";
    }
    public function setLeadImageAltAttribute($value)
    {
        // dd(1); // never executed
        $this->attributes['lead_image_alt'] = "Some text";
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function edit(Lead $lead)
{
    return view('leads.edit', ['lead' => $lead]);
}
```

Comment: Are you ever calling your accessor? I.e. if you do `$lead->lead_image_alt`, does the `dd(1)` trigger? These methods don't do anything until they are explicitly called... Also, if the database column is `lead_image_alt`, you might want to consider a different name, like `getLeadImageAltNewAttribute()`, and `$lead->lead_image_alt_new`; in my experience, I've never had success with mutators and accessors if they share the exact same name as their database counterpart.

Comment: I call it in my edit form, using the `old(... , $lead->lead_image_alt)`.

Comment: Then yeah, you might be running into an issue where it's not called due to sharing the same name as the database column. Try the other part of my comment (unique method name and database column name) and see if that changes it.